# Unpickling classes not defined on the receiving end

Tags: python, pickle

[As stated in the `pickle` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), classes are normally pickled in such a way that they require the exact same class to be present in a module on the receiving end. However, I do note that there's also some `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` methods for classes, which affect how their instances are pickled...

How feasible would it be to create a metaclass that would allow pickling and unpickling of the classes created from that metaclass (in other words, the instances of that metaclass) even without the classes being present on the receiving end? (Though I think the metaclass would probably have to be present.)

---

Would utilizing a `__reduce__()` method in the class or metaclass also be something to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes have to be somehow present on the receiving end, because methods are not stored with the objects.  So, I think that using a specific metaclass unfortunately can't help, here…

Comment: I know `marshal` doesn't work with user-defined classes, but would it be possible to utilize it with the function objects (or the code objects of those functions, though in that case you'd need to utilize `inspect.getfullargspec()` or something to make sure the default arguments and all that are stored) for the classes' methods? Utilizing `marshal.dumps()` and `marshal.loads()`...

Comment: Interesting points: there is hope (but I can't think of anything concrete off the top of my head). :)

Comment: The problem, I think, lies in the fact that code objects could change between versions of Python, and also that `marshal` isn't intended for serialization like `pickle` and thus there aren't any guarantees about breaking of backwards compatibility there... which I guess is why it's allowed to utilize code objects like that. I guess, in the end, the best course of action may simply be to send a class as a string (using `inspect.getsource()` to get the source code for the class), and just `exec` the string on the receiving end.